# Passing parameter into nested funtion

Tags: python, parameter-passing

I have a flag that is set via command line argument.  That flag is used by a function nested many layers deep.  What is the pythonic way to pass that flag (or any other variable) to a deeply nested function?  Adding it to every parameter list as I've done below doesn't feel right.

```
def func3(flag var3, var4):
...
# flag is used only here
 if flag;
   do something
 else:
 do something else

def func2(flag, var1, var2):
 ...
 x=func3(flag, c, d)

def func1(flag, var1, var2)
 ...
 y = func2(flag, a, b)


def def main():
...
parser.add_agrument('-f', '--flag', action='store_true' default=false)
...
result = func1(flag, foo, bar)
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using a class? This scenario could be pretty easily eliminated if you created a class variable and made all of these functions class methods.

Comment: If flag is only declared once and doesn't change, this may be one of the few cases where I might recommend using a global variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use Class as others have already suggested and need a simple workaround that doesn't make you change the code, use a global variable in that module, in all CAPS

Also, this in my mind is like how we use environment variables. Single variable, that is self explanatory and least likely to be changed mistakenly by anyone.

```py
def func3(var3, var4):
...
# flag is used only here
 if SOME_DISTINCT_FLAG;
   do something
 else:
 do something else

def func2(var1, var2):
 ...
 x=func3(c, d)

def func1(var1, var2):
 ...
 y = func2(a, b)


def def main():
...
parser.add_argument('-f', '--flag', action='store_true' default=false)
...
# this lets you access global variables
# without it, the variable will be of local scope
global SOME_DISTINCT_FLAG
SOME_DISTINCT_FLAG = flag
result = func1(foo, bar)
```

Also, you might define it at the top just to be clear what it is, and set a default value. No loose ends.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a class:

```py
class Example:

    def __init__(self, flag, a, b, c):
        self.flag = flag   
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d

    def func3(self):
        ...
        # flag is used only here
        if self.flag;
            do something
        else:
            do something else

    def func2(self):
        ...
        x=func3(self.flag, self.c, self.d)

    def func1(self)
        ...
        y = func2(self.flag, self.a, self.b)
```

This way you can access class variables at any nesting depth without needing to pass the variables through your call stack directly. This also affords access to those variables in other methods you develop later, without having to reinstantiate the values.